# Setting focus to a textbox on load of Windows Phone 7 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a TwoWay data-bound textbox inside my page. I want to do something pretty simple, but I can't for the life of me work out how to do it. When the page loads, I want to set the focus to the textbox if it doesn't have any text in it.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (tbSearch.Text == "")
        tbSearch.Focus();
}
```

This doesn't work. It doesn't fail, it just doesn't do anything. Am I doing something strange wrong? I've also tried putting this in the constructor, to no avail.

Chris

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Does doing this from the pages `Loaded` event work for your requirements?

It will work from there.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Do you have any idea why it doesn't work in the other events?

Comment: No worries Chris. I can only assume that the page hasn't fully loaded, allowing focus to be assigned to UI elements, at the time OnNavigatedTo is fired.

Comment: Still applicable in Windows 8. The controls haven't appeared on screen by the time OnNavigatedTo is called, but they are certainly there on Loaded.