# Keyboard poping up automatic in form

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to have keyboard that pops up automaticly in first textbox when user goes to some form page with textboxes?

I want to work it the same way like when I'm adding a new contact in People's Hub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the focus of the page after it loaded to the textbox should pop the keyboard up. There is no way with the current WP7 API to bring up the keyboard manually.

[Setting focus to a textbox on load of Windows Phone 7 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513222/setting-focus-to-a-textbox-on-load-of-windows-phone-7-app)